# How to get variable`s value of CSS from database in yii?

Tags: php, html, css, yii

I am working on app in which i need to get value of the color attribute from database(Hex value) to make it custom.
I searched on internet i found a solution that i can use css file as php file including this line in css file

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css;");
$bannerColor="#b229b6";
?>
```

when i select banner color in above code then i show it in css selector like this

```
#banner {
    background-color:<?php echo $bannerColor; ?>;
    width: 100%;
    height: 436px;
}
```

it works fine. But when i try to write query in php code(at the top of this php file), the css gets out of order on the main page where i have used this file. When i remove query code it works fine as earlier.

My question is that
1. Can i use `$banner=  Color::model()->findAll();` in this file? If Yes then what i am doing wrong here?

2. If it can not be used then how to accomplish this task?
 thanks for your help.

Comment: updated the answer :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yourcss.php don't have YII context within, you can:

In your main (layout) file, get your value from database and put into a cookie:

```
$banner= Color::model()->findAll();
$_COOKIE['bgColor'] = get your value from $banner
```

In yourcss.php file you should get this value from cookie as:

```
<style>
#banner {
background-color: <?php echo $_COOKIE['bgColor']; ?>;
width: 100%;
height: 436px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, working great for me. The only thing i changed from your code was writing cookies by using Yii::app()->request->cookies['bgColor'] = new CHttpCookie('bgColor', $bannerColor);